CMV: SI (nota musical) debería escribirse con tilde
Tengo la convicción de que la Academia tiene un criterio razonable detrás de todas las convenciones que adopta y que nos las recuerda a diario con sus tuits que no parecen ser más aportativos que lo que pudiera ser el recitar párrafos de memoria en un exámen y todo eso; aunque también es cierto que yerran feo algunas veces.
Estamos ante uno de esos casos? Claro, creía que esta gente se tiraba más para el lado de las grafías regulares que reflejen mejor la fonética y todo eso. Pero si es así entonces por qué la nota musical no llevaría tilde? Fundéu da buenos ejemplos:

El si lo da algo desafinado.

Que se pronuncia:

el SI lo DA algo DESAFINADO.

Tónico, por supuesto, al ser una palabra que agrega léxico al discurso. Invirtiendo la frase del último ejemplo que muestran, me queda que:

El sí se lo dieron los contrayentes.


el SI se lo DIERON los CONTRAYENTES.

De nuevo tónico. Algo que no sucedería con el si condicional, al tener una función meramente conectiva, lo que explica por qué no lleve tilde este último. Cito de nuevo a Fundéu para que no queden dudas:

La Academia señala asimismo que la tilde diacrítica «no se emplea en español para distinguir pares de palabras de igual forma y distinto significado que siempre son tónicas, como di del verbo decir y di del verbo dar», ambas sin tilde.

Exactamente lo que ocurre entre la nota musical, la afirmación y el pronombre reflexivo! Los tres son

de igual forma: se escriben igual, se pronuncian igual
de distinto significado: tres etimologías completamente distintas
siempre tónicas: por ser lexicales

En conclusión, mal la RAE al pedir que las unas se tilden y la otra no. De esta forma, la tilde pasa a tener la función de distinguir entre acepciones, en lugar de marcar el énfasis propio de los monosílabos tónicos por sobre sus versiones átonas. Después se andan quejando por la tilde en sólo.
Refutalo.
POSDATA que quizá sirva para elaborar la refutación. Qué pasa con la y mi? No son tónicas también, y sin embargo no llevan tilde como deberían (una para distinguir del artículo, otra para distinguir del pronombre posesivo, ambos átonos)? Será que alguna convención caprichosa dictaminó que la regla tónico-notónico no vale para las notas?

¿Y la pregunta es?

¿Qué significa CMV?

CMV = Cambien Mi Visión. Era una práctica común cuando posteaba en un subreddit con el mismo nombre jeje.

Nunca lo había visto. Bueno, ya sé una cosa más.

La RAE dice que, efectivamente, estamos frente a una excepción (las negritas son mías):

Información adicional
Aunque, por lo general, se escriben con tilde diacrítica estos monosílabos cuando se trata de palabras tónicas y sin ella cuando son palabras átonas, se observan algunas pequeñas excepciones a esta pauta, como es el caso de los nombres de las letras te y de, y los de las notas musicales mi y si, que no llevan tilde diacrítica —aun siendo, por su condición de sustantivos, voces tónicas—, sino que cumplen la regla general que prescribe que los monosílabos se escriben sin tilde. Su ausencia del repertorio consolidado de monosílabos afectados por la tilde diacrítica se debe probablemente a que, con esos valores, son palabras de baja frecuencia de uso en la lengua corriente, y su distinción gráfica de su homónimo átono no resulta rentable.

La clave está muy bien expresada en la frase final: "son palabras de baja frecuencia de uso en la lengua corriente, y su distinción gráfica de su homónimo átono no resulta rentable."
Yo hubiera dicho "conveniente" en lugar de "rentable", pero la idea es, para qué malgastar una tilde en palabras léxicas de poca frecuencia, como los nombres de dos letras o los nombres de dos notas musicales: mejor reservarlos para palabras léxicas de mayor frecuencia, como el imperativo "dé", el sustantivo "té", el adverbio y el pronombre "sí" y el pronombre "mí".
También puede encontrarse un tweet de la RAE que dice:

La tilde diacrítica solo afecta a palabras con alta frecuencia de uso en español y no voces usadas solo en ciertos ámbitos. Por eso precisamente, los nombres de las notas musicales «si» y «mi», que son palabras tónicas, no llevan tilde.

Por último, creo que la escala musical se vería muy heterogénea si alternara notas con tilde y notas sin tilde: * do, re, mí, fa, sol, lá, sí

Jaja me encantó, simple y sencillo
